# Hspec: discovery, custom main, and passing argument to spec

Tags: haskell, hspec

I am trying to use `hspec-discover` along with custom `Main`. Custom `Main` is a `bracket` that creates a file descriptor to be used by all `Spec`'s.

This is my `Spec.hs`:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF hspec-discover -optF --module-name=Spec #-}
```

This is my `Main.hs`:

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Exception
import System.Posix.IO
import System.Posix.Files
import Test.Hspec
import Spec (spec)

main :: IO ()
main = bracket
  (openFd verybigFile ReadWrite (Just 384) defaultFileFlags)
  (\fd -> closeFd fd >> removeLink verybigFile)
  (\fd -> hspec (spec fd))
    where
      verybigFile = "test/verybigFile"
```

For my `spec` in individual autodiscovered module to accept the file descriptor argument, I need to declare it as

```
spec :: Fd -> Spec
```

but `hspec-discover` demands that spec is declared as

```
spec :: Spec
```

otherwise autogenerated module does not compile:

```
test/Spec.hs:8:68:
    Couldn't match type `System.Posix.Types.Fd -> Spec'
                  with `hspec-core-2.1.7:Test.Hspec.Core.Spec.Monad.SpecM () ()'
    Expected type: hspec-core-2.1.7:Test.Hspec.Core.Spec.Monad.SpecWith
                     ()
      Actual type: System.Posix.Types.Fd -> Spec
    In the second argument of `describe', namely `SendfileSpec.spec'
    In the second argument of `postProcessSpec', namely
      `(describe "Sendfile" SendfileSpec.spec)'
    In the expression:
      postProcessSpec
        "test/SendfileSpec.hs" (describe "Sendfile" SendfileSpec.spec)
```

So, how to pass an argument to the spec without disturbing autodiscovery? My imagination drifts towards `IORef`'s but the idea makes me shudder. What would be a Right Way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing values across spec files is currently not support with `hspec-discover`.  But you can still share values within the same spec file.  The following works:

`FooSpec.hs`:

```
module FooSpec (spec) where

import           Test.Hspec
import           System.IO

spec :: Spec
spec = beforeAll (openFile "foo.txt" ReadMode) $ afterAll hClose $ do
  describe "hGetLine" $ do
    it "reads a line" $ \h -> do
      hGetLine h `shouldReturn` "foo"

    it "reads an other line" $ \h -> do
      hGetLine h `shouldReturn` "bar"
```

`Spec.hs`:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF hspec-discover #-}
```

But note that `beforeAll` is generally considered a code smell.  It's good practice to use `before` instead if possible.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't it be a good idea to have an "official" way to create common environment for a group of tests (context, one spec, all specs) and pass it over?

Comment: Another way around it is to use `hooks` described here https://hspec.github.io/hspec-discover.html